# Did Tony Stark Know Jarvis?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, iron-man, agent-carter

In *Avengers: Endgame* (and *Agent Carter*), we learn that Howard Stark's 'personal assistant' was called Edwin Jarvis. We have heard this name before, however: J.A.R.V.I.S was the name of Tony's AI that later became part of the Vision.

In order for Tony to name his AI after Jarvis, he must've been important to Tony. How did Jarvis and Tony have a relationship? Did Jarvis look after Tony, after the death of his parents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not shown in the movies but yes, I believe this is covered in in the canon comic [**Iron Man 2: Public Identity**](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man_2:_Public_Identity#Issue_#3)

> Years later, Howard is working in his home office when a toy car runs into his foot. Angry, Howard berates Tony for wasting his time during his weekends at home. Tony runs away, and Howard feels bad for being so strict with his son. Tony sits alone crying on the balcony where he is found by Edwin Jarvis, the family's butler. Jarvis comforts Tony, telling him that a father-son relationship is difficult for both sides, but time will heal all wounds.

> [**After Tony graduated from MIT**](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Edwin_Jarvis#Serving_the_Stark_Family) and came home from Cambridge, Jarvis found Howard talking to his son while he was relaxing in a pool and informed Howard that his wife was waiting for him in the car. Howard told Jarvis to tell Maria that he would be right out.

> Jarvis raised Tony following the death of Howard and Maria, becoming a father-figure for the man until his own death.